# Tkinter treeview identify_element() method returns "padding"

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to implement drag and drop in tkinter treeview using the identify_element() method to indicate where I need to insert items.

When the `<ButtonRelease-1>` event gets triggered I call identify_element() it returns the word "padding" and not the treeview item. I have know idea why it's not returning the item at the x/y coords like it's supposed to do.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Ttk Treeview")

        abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
        self.nodes = {}
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        self.tree.heading("#0", text=abspath, anchor=tk.W)
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)

        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N + tk.S)
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.tree.bind("<<TreeviewOpen>>", self.open_node)

        def button_release(e):
            print('Results =', self.tree.identify_element(e.x, e.y))

        self.tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", button_release)

        self.populate_node("", abspath)

    def populate_node(self, parent, abspath):
        try:
            for entry in os.listdir(abspath):
                entry_path = os.path.join(abspath, entry)

                node = self.tree.insert(parent, tk.END, text=entry, open=False)
                if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
                    self.nodes[node] = entry_path
                    self.tree.insert(node, tk.END)
        except:
            messagebox.showerror('Access Denied', f'Sorry you do not have access privileges for, {abspath}.')

    def open_node(self, _):
        item = self.tree.focus()
        abspath = self.nodes.pop(item, False)
        if abspath:
            children = self.tree.get_children(item)
            self.tree.delete(children)
            self.populate_node(item, abspath)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App(path="/")
    app.mainloop()
```

I expect that the output of identify_element() should return an treeview item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`identify_element` is designed to return what part of the widget was clicked on (ie: one of the elements defined in the treeview layout), not which item you clicked on.

In tcl/tk you would use `.tree identify item` rather than `.tree identify element`. Oddly, tkinter doesn't provide an analogous `identify_item` method. However, it does expose the generic `identify` method, which can be passed `"item"` as its first parameter to identify the tree item id under the cursor.

```
print('Results =', self.tree.identify("item", e.x, e.y))
```